# Build MSpec test with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, mspec

I am trying to set up TeamCity. Initially, I ran into various issues but after much trial and error, I managed to perform a successful build. So I know that I can get a cut down version of my solution to build successfully.

However, one of the items that was problematic was my MSpec test. When I configured my solution to build the MSpec test project I get the following erro:

> Areas\Manufacturing\Controllers\DashboardControllerSpecs.cs(7, 30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Hosts' does not exist in the namespace 'CompanyName.ApplicationName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The fact is that it builds "fine" on my local machine but on the build server, which happens to be on my local machine, I get the error above.

What could I be doing wrong? What are the things that I should be checking to find out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I think I've found what I was doing wrong. Effectively, we were doing version numbering in the MSBuild file. The target name was specified as "BeforeBuild". To get TeamCity to build this, I ended up changing this to "Build". The end result was that without the Spec project, TeamCity was building this fine but had trouble with it when the Spec project was included in the build.

I don't know enough to even speculate why this was happening. However, the solution was to remove the section in the MSBuild file and let TeamCity manage version numbering.

Comment: Glad you finally found it! I was completely at a loss, as you probably noticed :) If this is how you solved it, you might want to mark your own answer as the right one. It will make it easier for people to find the right solution in the future.

Comment: @Sergi - I hesitate to mark it down as my answer. I know it could turn out to be helpful but our set up is quite particular I'd say. But yes I'll mark it when I'm allowed to do so :). Now I'm running into another problem and your help would be greatly appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578031/unable-to-run-mspec-test-due-to-the-fact-that-teamcity-is-building-test-assembly

Comment: I've taken a look at your other question and I'm afraid I don't even know where to begin :(

Comment: @Sergi - Yes it seems that for some reason I manage to get into these weird situations whereby there doesn't seem to be anyone else in the same situation. :S. I think I might have to give up on TeamCity although I really don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious one is of course, are you bin deploying (setting the `Copy to Local` option to `true`) all the references assemblies that are not on the `GAC`?
You might want to particularly check that the `Machine.Specifications` dll is set to `Copy to Local`.

Is `Hosts` a type or namespace in your app? It's not part of Mspec in any case, I've just checked.

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, "Hosts" is a folder in the namespace and Copy to Local option is set to true

Comment: @David - Mhm.. Is the folder structure created correctly on the "build server"? I mean, does the `Hosts` folder appear on disk inside the deploymed folder?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit - As I'm new to Teamcity if by appear on disk inside the deployment folder, you mean under the "../TeamCity/buildAgent/work" folder (I've set up TeamCity with the default options), then yes the folder structure appears on disk. However, I cannot see any "Deployment" folder as such. Where might that be?

Comment: @David - The ".../work" folder is what I meant, sorry; I just meant the folder structure that team city uses to tart the build. And without the "specs" project everything works fine?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit- Yes without the specs project the build is successful.

Comment: @David - You says `Copy To Local` is set to `true`. Is this also the case for the `Machine.Specifications` dll in you specs project? Is TeamCity supposed to run your MSpec tests?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit - I will have to check that it's also set to true for the Machine.Specifications dll tomorrow. TeamCity isn't configured to run the MSpec tests, at least I don't think I did. I'm going to do that as the next step. For the moment, I only want the solution to compile.

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit - I've just checked and the Machine.Specifications dll has "Copy to Local" is set to true. But question for you. Why am I verifying these settings? The error message doesn't seem to point in that direction or am I missing something? Btw thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @David - I was asking about these settings because one would deduce from the error message that some types cannot be found. And since the problem seems to lie in the specs project, I just wanted to get the obvious out of the way. You're more than welcome, and I'm sorry for the (so far pointless) back and forth...

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit - Well it's not a pointless back and forth since I'm learning release management along the way. I'm the one who has got to apologise for taking your time away.