# Unable to run MSpec test due to the fact that TeamCity is building test assembly wrong

Tags: teamcity, mspec

I am trying to run a MSpec test following the build of my solution. So, I've got my MSBuild script set up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
      <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="../MyApplication.Web.sln" />
        <Message Text="Building solution" Importance="high" />
      </Target>

      <Target Name="TeamCity" DependsOnTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="Before executing MSpec command" Importance="high" />
        <Exec Command="mspec.exe ..\Hosts\MyApplication.Hosts.Web.Specs\bin\MyApplication.Hosts.Web.Specs.dll --teamcity" />
        <Message Text="Running MSpec" Importance="high" />  
      </Target>
    </Project>
```

I then call "TeamCity" as my target in TeamCity. When the command

> "mspec.exe
>   ..\Hosts\MyApplication.Hosts.Web.Specs\bin\MyApplication.Hosts.Web.Specs.dll
>   --teamcity"

is executed, I get the following error:

> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\117e3aa3bb76aad0\Build>mspec ..\Hosts\Application.Hos
>   ts.Web.Specs\bin\Application.Hosts.Web.Specs.dll
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\117e3aa3bb7
>   6aad0\Hosts\Application.Hosts.Web.Specs\bin\Application.Hosts.Web.Specs.dll' or on
>   e of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect f
>   ormat.

After doing some investigation, I found out that the "MyApplication.Hosts.Web.Specs.dll" on my local machine and the build server, although both 15kb, had different md5 checksums. That might explain why the execution of the MSpec test would cause errors. In fact, if I copy the dll from my local machine to the build server, the test will run.

So my question is whether someone else has come across this same issue of the builiding of assemblies being build "badly"?

-EDIT-
Locally I'm building the solution as a 64 bit application but in TeamCity, I'm building it as 32 bits (x86). Could that be the problem?

PS:I tried building it as a 64 bit application in TeamCity but I get other errors which I would rather ignore for the moment. However, for completeness sake here it is:

```
Client\ProdMaster.SLCharts\ProdMaster.SLCharts.csproj
[15:11:22]: [Client\ProdMaster.SLCharts\ProdMaster.SLCharts.csproj] GetFrameworkPaths
[15:11:22]: [GetFrameworkPaths] ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths
[15:11:22]: [ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(104, 9): The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed.
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the exact error message?

Comment: @Sergi - Thanks for helping out! I've edited the OP and included the details of the error message.

Comment: @Sergi - Alexander provided me with the answer. It was quite a slog but got there in the end :)

Comment: Glad to hear you're slowly but surely getting rid of al your MSpec/TeamCity problems :)

Comment: @Sergi - Yes slowly is the right word. :). I'm sure that there will be other problems but hopefully not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David,

- Which version of MSpec are you
  running? If you're still on 0.3.0.0 I
  encourage you to switch to the [most
  recent 0.4.9.0 build](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/guestAuth/repository/download/bt342/.lastSuccessful/Machine.Specifications-Release.zip). This build
  contains mspec.exe (AnyCPU) as well
  as mspec-x86.exe (x86). You should
  use the executable matching your build
  environment/architecture.
- Can you please trace the assembly
  binding with Fustion Log Viewer -
  it's part of the Windows SDK. The
  error message "An attempt was made to
  load a program with an incorrect
  format." indicates that MSpec is able
  to find the spec DLL, but target
  architectures do not match between
  the MSpec executable and and spec
  assembly.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I indeed have the older version and I will update it and let you know what the deal is.

Comment: I've updated to the latest build i.e. 0.4.9.0. I am using mspec.exe (AnyCPU). However, I still get the same error. So I tried using Fusion Log Viewer and I'm logging everything. However, in the list, the Application.Hosts.Web.dll is in there but the Application.Hosts.Web.Specs doesn't appear in the list. Please bear in mind that it's the first time I use Fusion Log Viewer but I believe I'm doing it correctly because when I run the test locally I can see the Application.Host.Web.Spec in the list.

Comment: I've just looked at the logs in Teamcity and this time the error message is slightly different: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. I'll try and figure out how to fix that. TBC

Comment: I've finally worked out how to do this. So I got the latest build. Then I used mspec-clr4.exe since my whole solution is built against that and a x64 architecture.